# Retirar caracteres especiais SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

como faço para retirar os caracteres especiais de uma string em uma query no SQL Server com tags em html, xml e outros?

Resultado atual:

```
<!--[if !mso]><styl>v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}w\:*...
```

Tentei utilizar o char, mas sem sucesso. Segue a query abaixo.

```
select
REPLACE(REPLACE(m.msg_body, CHAR(13), ' ' ),CHAR(10), ' ' ) as Descrição
from service_req_msg m
```

Comment: Ue, mas o que vc queria que mostrasse?

Comment: @Sorack, o texto contido nele. Nesse caso "Prezado, favor, mostrar..."

Comment: Mas no seu exemplo não tem esse texto em lugar nenhum